# Ng2 router not recognizing child route

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

So, I have a layout like this:

```
<div class="page-container">

    <app-header></app-header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

            <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>

            <app-broadcast-show></app-broadcast-show>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And all components are working well with this, except for one. This is my Router array:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
    {
        path: 'admin', component: MainComponent, children: [
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'fund_transfers/deposits',
            component: FundTransfersComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'edit',
                    component: DepositComponent
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            path: 'fund_transfers/withdrawals',
            component: FundTransfersComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'profile',
            component: ProfileComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'broadcast',
            component: BroadcastCreateComponent
        }
    ]
    },
];
```

Route

```
children: [
                {
                    path: 'edit',
                    component: DepositComponent
                },
            ],
```

Doesn't show when I click on a button that is leading there. I registered Component, created it like I created the rest of the components that are working, but it is not triggering constructor nor onInit, nor is it hiding the previous view and showing the deposit/edit.

Anybody has any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out whats going on. If using route as child, then in the parent html I need to set router-outlet, not in the first in line, in my case, `admin`, but rather in `fund_transfers/deposits`.